# What is the courteous amount of time I should wait before I refer someone to my new company?

Tags: referral

## Background

I (thankfully) recently accepted a very good offer at a new company.  One of my colleagues from college has been looking for a new job as well for a very long time and is currently at a contracting job while she still searches for a full time job.  I really do want to refer her to my new company because, as far as I know, it doesn't have a strict citizenship requirement.  But I have a feeling that joining then instantly referring someone (or several people) seems like bad courtesy.  To be sure, I wanted to confirm this with the following question.

## Question

How long should I wait before I begin referring colleagues to my new company?

Comment: @Kilisi Specific job openings

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**They hired you, so they already value you.**

I was referred to my current company by someone who had been there two months. A week later, the VP asked me if there was anyone I had in mind as they were thinking of spinning up another software team.

I wouldn't worry about tenure when it comes to referring people. They chose you over a pile of others and presumably would like to avoid going through that pile if they need another of you.

Comment: The only thing I would add is not to go poaching multiple people from the company you just left.

Answer (score 2):

As a manager I would think exactly the opposite. If you as a new employee were already referring good candidates it would be a major positive in how I viewed you as an employee.
You are helping the company!